# Angular - delaying loading of templateUrl until modal is loaded?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I am using $modal for opening modals.

I have a modal that contains a ui-view.  States using the ui-view need to wait until the modal has been added into the DOM, otherwise the states will not find the ui-view to load templates into.

Anyone have a good way for delaying the loading of a template?  I have considered a promise that resolves once the modal's controller has been initialized, but I fear it is overcomplicating things.

Thanks

Comment: What have yo tried yet? We may need some code yo help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone is going down the same road, I ended up using Jquery-based foundation for my modal control, rather than the angular-foundation $modal service.  With the jquery foundation modals, I can add a hidden modal div to my main template, containing the ui-view.  So there is never any waiting for the modal to be appended to the DOM.  Activating the modal is just unhiding the modal's div.  This solved all timing issues and works as intended.

Comment: I may have to do the same. Not sure why Angular (sans jQuery code) hasn't provided a way to load big modals smoothly.